# How to rsync a folder and subfolders using filenames only?

Tags: linux, rsync

I would like to synchronize files from the folder `/media/alex/Disk1/Movies` to the folder named `/media/alex/Disk2/Movies`. I want to copy *each* file from `/media/alex/Disk1/Movies` or a subdirectory to the correct position `/media/alex/Disk2/Movies`, if it does not exist. The size and the time attributes of the files do not matter.

For example, I have a single file that exists only on Disk1: `/media/alex/Disk1/Movies/Experimental/test.avi`, so only this single file should get copied to `/media/alex/Disk2/Movies/Experimental`.

I have tried using the syntax

```
rsync -v -n -auv  --list-only /media/alex/Disk1/Movies  /media/alex/Disk2/Movies
```

but it lists *all* files in the directory '/media/alex/Disk1/Movies', even the ones that exist under `/media/alex/Disk3/Movies`. How to get the `rsync` Syntax right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
rsync -n -auv --size-only /media/alex/Disk1/Movies/  /media/alex/Disk2/Movies
```

and if that does what you want, you can remove the `-n` argument

Some explanation:

- `--size-only` makes sure you do not have to touch the movies in the destination folder to do checksumming and you don't care if the time is different (since the content of the movie files does not change, this should be OK)
- the syntax of `rsync` can be a bit confusing. In your example, you omitted the `/` behind `/media/alex/Disk1/Movies`, which will actually copy the whole Movie-folder into the OTHER Movie-folder (so it will be `/media/alex/Disk2/Movies/Movies`)

Comment: I thought I tried that one before, but maybe I used an extra '/' or something...

Comment: @Alex yes, bad things will happen if you omit the '/'. You could, however, use `rsync -n -auv --size-only /media/alex/Disk1/Movies /media/alex/Disk2`